# Not all algebraic curves can be parametrized by rational or polynomial function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I learned that given a curve parametrized by rational functions, we can use elimination theory (via grobner basis) or resultants to get the implicitization. However, I don't know how to prove that 'not all algebraic curves could be parametrized by rational functions'. Can anyone suggest a good reference to this topic or give me some ideas how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to see this is that giving a rational parametrization of a smooth projective curve $X$ is same as giving a surjective morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to X$. If such a map existed and if $X$ had a non-zero holomorphic form, it pulls back to one such on the projective line, which has none. So, $X$ has none and the dimension of the vector space of holomorphic forms being genus, one gets genus of $X$ is zero. So, such a parametrization exists if and only if genus is zero.